# How do I initialize data for Flux using Gulp and Browserify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, flux

I am using Gulp and Browserify to generate a bundle.js file.

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    browserify('./js/app.js')
        .transform(reactify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
   });
```

I am now trying to initialize my Flux application with data from the server so that there is no wait time when the page loads.

According to Bill Fisher this should be done in a bootstrap file like this one (slide 62): https://speakerdeck.com/fisherwebdev/flux-meetup#62

My question is where is the bootstrap function being called?

I have seen people using the command line to generate a bundle that allows you to use require in the global scope. I have also seen people put their JSON data into `script` tags and assign it to the window variable.

This all seems very messy to me. What's the best practice for this?

I would prefer:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    MyApp.initialize({{json}});
</script>
```

Also, the data I'm loading is from a database. As most of the Flux examples so far only use `localStorage` it doesn't help me when trying to asynchronously load data.

Comment: I think you should have a topmost app.js file which renders the topmost react element, and also fires the initial "load data" action. You can use ajax to load the initial data, and put the request either into an ActionCreator or into the Store. Both have pros, and cons. Putting initial data loading, and ajax requests into an ActionCreator leaves the store only handle synchronous operations, but putting these requests into the Stores fits better for SoC (Separation of Concerns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer somewhere online; add `{standalone: 'app_name'}` to your config.

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    browserify('./js/app.js', {standalone: 'MyApp'})
        .transform(reactify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

Then you can do `new MyApp()` from within script tags on your page.

---

**Update 09/09/15** New Approach

I have since changed my approach to using [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) instead of reactify and no longer having to call my javascript from inside script tags.

```
var b = watchify(browserify('js/index.js', {
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    debug: true,
    fullPaths: true,
    transform: ['babelify']
}));

function bundler () {
    b.bundle()
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify error.'))
        .pipe(source('build.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/js'));
}

gulp.task('backend:scripts', bundler);
b.on('update', bundler);
b.on('log', gutil.log);
```

Also, should note that regarding the original question and bootstrapping data I now use [express-state](https://github.com/yahoo/express-state).

```
res.expose({
    users: users,
    posts: posts
});
```

And then in your handlebars file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">{{{state}}}</script>
<script src="/js/build.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And all your data is available on the `window` variable for bootstrapping within your code.